# Create custom Queue class with O(1) Enqueue and O(1) Dequeue

Tags: c#, linked-list, queue, complexity

I am implementing a Queue class in C# using a Node/LinkedList class that I also implemented, and I wonder if there is a way to implement the enqueue and the dequeue methods, both in algorithmic efficiency of \$O(1)\$.

In the `Queue` class I have a field of the tail and the head, and I managed to implement the enqueue method in \$O(1)\$, but the dequeue is \$O(n)\$.

This is the code for the `Node` and the `Queue` classes:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    #region Fields

    private Node<T> next;
    private T data;

    #endregion Fields


    #region Constructors

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node(T data) : this(data, null)
    {

    }

    #endregion Constructors


    #region Properties

    public Node<T> Next
    {
        get { return next; }
        set { next = value; }
    }

    public T Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    #endregion Properties


    #region Methods

    public bool HasNext()
    {
        return next != null;
    }

    #endregion Methods
}




public class Queue<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    public Queue()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T data)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            head = new Node<T>(data);
        else if (tail == null)  // There is only one element in the queue
            tail = new Node<T>(data, head);
        else
            tail = new Node<T>(data, tail);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");

        T data = head.Data;

        if (tail == null)  // There is only one element in the queue
        {
            head = null;
            return data;
        }

        Node<T> temp = tail;

        while (temp.Next != head)  // Get the previous Node of the head
            temp = temp.Next;

        temp.Next = null;
        head = temp;

        if (tail == head)
            tail = null;

        return data;
    }

    public T Head()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");

        return head.Data;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return head == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Does it actually do something yet?

Comment: @Mast yes, it works, but I want to find out if there is a way for the `Dequeue` method to be \$O(1)\$ instead of \$O(n)\$.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is your bottleneck in retrieving the new head at removal, which can not be avoided in a Singly-Linked structure, so it's \$O(n)\$.

> ```
> while (temp.Next != head)  // Get the previous Node of the head
>     temp = temp.Next;
> ```

### Doubly-Linked

If you want fast removal \$O(1)\$, you can do so at the cost of slightly slower insertion. You'd need to augment the queue to a doubly linked queue:

```
var previous = head.Previous;
head.Previous = null;
head = previous;
head.Next = null;
```

Make sure at insertion, you'll set both `Previous` as `Next` references on the relevant nodes.

### Circular Doubly-Linked

If you make the queue circular, you don't even need to store the `tail`, only the `head`. The `tail` would be `head.Previous`; In case of a single element, since it's circular, `head.Previous` would point to `head`. Make sure in iterators to terminate at `head`, instead of at `null`.

Comment: Cheater! Writing off-topic reviews and restoring them when the question is fixed :-P

Comment: Who could have seen that missing _Node_ class? :p

Comment: @dfhwze Why the line `head.Previous = null;` is needed? The line `head.Next = null;` won't delete the reference to the old head? (so the garbage collector will delete it anyway, even if I didn't set the previous to null).

Comment: You are right, it's just a proper way to clean references. By not clearing the previous reference on the former head, you'd might want to reuse that head later on. There is a thing called 'cloacking' in which a 'removed' node could put itself back in the list.

Comment: Be careful though by asserting it will be garbage collected. Even though the queue no longer references the old head, a consumer may still hold a reference to it. So removing the reference to Previous is required.